# Access denied AADSTS650053 error when connecting to Azure DevOps Analytics via OData

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I am trying to connect to Azure DevOps from Power BI using oData Feed and getting the below error.
Can you help me with the resolution or steps that I shall be taking to get rid of this error?

```
access_denied: AADSTS650053: The application 'Microsoft Power Query for Excel' asked for scope 'user_impersonation' that doesn't exist on the resource 'a4ce0e36-87e6-4227-bad6-bad83309a7c9'. Contact the app vendor.
Trace ID: 553717b9-66ff-48a7-ad85-261f26296200
Correlation ID: ff6e41ca-50c9-4d0a-b570-af216986b9ed
Timestamp: 2023-05-19 07:08:55Z.
```

I am able to connect to Azure Analytics View from Power BI without any issues and checked the Analytics permission on the Project for my User and it has access. Here is the screen capture of the same.

[image: ADO Project Permission]